# How do you handle application that displays only views with EF4 plus Repository Pattern?

Tags: sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-4, view, entity-framework-4.1

I have database that has 5 views (SQL Server 2008) and the client requires a front-end web (MVC4) to view the data with filters. I am using Entity Framework 4 to map to the database...Not sure how to adjust implementation of the Repository pattern which usually enforces CRUD. The application is read-only, no DELETE, ADD or UPDATE. Just GET and filtering ability?

Comment: Maybe you should first ask the question how you can offer read-only data in the most simple way. Why would you need a repository at all? And when you can present the view data as-is you don't even need a view model. So maybe filtering a DbSet is all that's left.

Comment: Good Point Gert, I sometimes get stuck on following conventions and patterns..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, in implementing a repository pattern you would do something like:

```
public class ReadOnlyRepository<TEntity> : IReadOnlyRepository
    where TEntity : class
{
    // Read-only methods here
}

public class Repository<TEntity> : ReadOnlyRepository<TEntity>, IRepository
    where TEntity : class
{
    // Write methods here
}
```

You could then inject `ReadOnlyRepository<SomeReadOnlyEntity>` where you want read-only access.

As far as Entity Framework goes, it works pretty seamlessly with views. You just need to specify the view your entity should attach to as a table name:

```
[Table("SomeView")]
public class SomeEntityFromView
{
    ...
}
```